# How to obtain top n values for each row in a dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a huge df (64001 rows x 1600 columns), and i need both **column name** & **Value of the corresponding column**. So far i managed to obtain the **column name** and create a data frame with them, as shown below.

Original data frame overview:

[image]

using this code:

```
df=df.apply(lambda s: s.abs().nlargest(5).index.tolist(), axis=1)
df=df.to_frame()
df[['MS_filename_1','MS_filename_2', 'MS_filename_3', 'MS_filename_4', 'MS_filename_5']] = pd.DataFrame(df[0].values.tolist(),index= df.index)
df = df.drop([0], axis=1)
```

Output:

[image]

My desired output will be another table like the lastone but instead of the **Column names** it should show the **Top n values** (top 1, 2, 3, 4 & 5).

I would appreciate a glimpse on how to get that second table.

Luis

Comment: Please paste your data instead of embedding a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do:

```
# minimal example
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': pd.np.random.randint(2, 20, 6),
                  'col2': pd.np.random.randint(2, 20, 6),
                  'col3': pd.np.random.randint(2, 20, 6)})

# set it accordingly
topn = 2
newdf = df.apply(np.sort, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x[:n]).apply(pd.Series)
newdf.columns = ['MS_filename_1','MS_filename_2']

   MS_filename_1  MS_filename_2
0              3              6
1              8             10
2              3              5
3              4             16
4              4              8
5              7             13
```

Hope this gives you some idea.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i see that always the MS_filename_1 is smaller tan MS_filename_2 int he corresponding index. But what i want is ti have the largest  value in the MS_filename_1, then the second largest in MS_filename2, and so on, for every row. Can you guide me? Thansk